# Resource Governor exception while retrieving data form database

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlanywhere

I am retrieving a large amount of data from database. When code starts, it works fine for sometime after that it gives following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -685: Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded​
```

I tried finding it on stackoverflow but not able to resolve this.

Also many times connection itself gets close even I haven't written any connection.close statement.

I read somewhere that DBA has authority to resolve it. Is there is any way I can do it in my jdbc code.

Please help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved..as some of the statements were not closed, still if someone has another reason and solution you are still welcomed.I may be wrong as I am new to jdbc.